# Modular Forms Over Quadratic Number Fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, class-field-theory

I'm trying to do a bit of reading and looking into mislay forms of weight one over quadratic number fields, but am finding it difficult to locate any books or papers. I've got a little material from Miyake's book, but not much. Can anyone give me a little direction on where to look?

Comment: Are you interested in real quad. fields or imaginary quad. fields?  These are pretty different beasts!